# GNUPG Decryption command line

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Am trying to decrypt an encrypted file, I have all the keys in place (secret and public), I don't know why its not generating output file. Following are the commands am running. I know there are several post already there but I cant refer them until and unless any error flashes on my command prompt.

> gpg --list-secret-keys

```
Its listing secret keys
```

> gpg --list-keys

```
Its listing all keys
```

> gpg --import "c:\folder_location\name_PublicKey.gpg"

`successfully imported keys`

> gpg  --batch --yes --passphrase my_passphrase  --local-user "mycomp name
>   " -o "c:\folder_location\filenameTEST.txt" -d
>   "c:\folder_location\ENCRYPTEDFILE.txt.gpg"

Am not able to decrypt file on command line, There is no error reported on command prompt. Command remains Active all the time, needed force close.

Anything am missing here to check? any suggestions?

Comment: Whats the output of the basic decrypt :  `gpg -d "c:\folder_location\ENCRYPTEDFILE.txt.gpg"`

Comment: prompted and given passphrase....decrypt process started ...i can see decrypted data on command line

Comment: @Pogrindis thanks, your comment helped me to identify real problem

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with my command, actual problem was **CR and LF control characters** (new line). When I removed those characters, decryption worked without any errors! GPG never detected these characters and statement got parsed without any error, and later command froze without any error/output.